# Open neighborhood of a subset of a metric space

Tags: general-topology, continuity, metric-spaces

Suppose $X$ is a metric space, with distance function $d:X\times X\to \Bbb R$. Also suppose $U$ is an open neighborhood of a subset $A\subset X$. Then for each $a\in A$, we can choose an  $\epsilon_a>0$ such that the ball $B(a,\epsilon_a)$ is contained in $U$. My question is: can we choose a continuous function $\epsilon:A\to \Bbb R$ such that $B(a,\epsilon(a))$ is contained in $U$ for all $a\in A$?

Actually I want this situation when $X=\Bbb R^n$, but I'm wondering if this holds in this general situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $\epsilon(a) =d(a, U^{c}) (\equiv \inf \{d(a,b): b \notin U\}$ is such a  function.  In fact $|\epsilon(a)-\epsilon(a')| \leq d(a,a')$.

[ $\epsilon (a) \leq d(a,b) \leq d(a,a')+d(a',b)$ for all $b \in U^{c}$. Take infimum  over $b$ to see that $\epsilon (a) \leq \epsilon (a') +d(a,a')$. Simialrly, $\epsilon (a') \leq \epsilon (a) +d(a,a')$. so $|\epsilon (a) - \epsilon (a')| \leq d(a,a')$].

Answer (score 0):

Let $A\subset X$ open. If $A=X$, then $f(x)\equiv 1$ does our job.

If $X\setminus A\ne\varnothing$, we can define $f:A\to\mathbb R$ as
$$
f(x)={\mathrm{dist}}(x,X\setminus A).
$$
If $x,y\in A$ and $z\in X\setminus A$, then
$$
d(x,z)\le d(x,y)+d(y,z)
$$
Clearly
$$
f(x)=\inf\{d(x,w):w\in X\setminus A\}\le d(x,z)\le d(x,y)+d(y,z)
$$
and hence
$$
f(x)\le d(x,y)+d(y,z), \quad\text{for all $z\in X\setminus A$}
$$
Thus
$$
f(x)\le d(x,y)+\inf_{z\in X\setminus A} d(y,z)=d(x,y)+f(y).
$$
Similarly we obtain
$$
f(y)\le d(x,y)+f(x),
$$
and hence
$$
|f(x)-f(y)|\le d(x,y),
$$
i.e. $f$ uniformly continuous.